# Getting version name from git-tag when deploying from travis-ci to bintray

Tags: travis-ci, bintray

I would like to deploy some js files to bintray, reading the instructions on http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/bintray/ I see that the name of the version is configured in the descriptor file. I would like it to use the git-tag instead. So that to make a release I only need to push a tag without having to modify a configuration file on each release. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the built-in environment variables. The one that you are looking for is `TRAVIS_TAG`. [The full list is here.](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables)

Comment: Thanks, but how to use environment variables in the deployment descriptor? I could of course have a script invoked from.travis.yml that creates the deployment json file but I hope that there is a more straight forward way.

Comment: ${} does not work. any other idea? im facing the same problem.

Comment: Looks like a Travis bug. Worth checking with their support. Please keep us posted!

Comment: @JBaruch bintray deployment uses a seperate json descriptor file. Afaik it doesn't support variable substitution

Answer (score 1):

you have to generate the descriptor file as part of your build. There you can check the environment variable using e.g. python or shell.